# node.js, express and different ports

Tags: node.js, express

I've been playing with node.js and then came across the express framework. I can't seem to get it to work when different ports are being used.

I have my ajax on http://localhost:8888 which is a MAMP server I'm running on my Mac.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:1337/",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { }, 
    contentType: "application/json",
    cache: false,
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

As you can see my node.js server is running on http://localhost:1337/. As a result nothing is getting returned and it's throwing an error.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks

Ben

Comment: The way I understand your question, you're loading a webpage from localhost:8888 that then does a $.ajax call to localhost:1337. Is that correct? If so, then you're hitting the same origin policy.

Comment: That's correct. So the only way around this is to run my website off the node.js server so it has the same port? But what if I have this live on my website hosted on port 80 and I want to connect to the node.js server in order to make a request such as a search? How do most people do this?

Comment: The preferred approach (IMHO) is to use a reverse proxy, make all requests go to the same host/port and reroute them behind the scenes. A not-uncommon workaround is to use JSONP, but I personally don't like that because of its security implications.

Comment: As @BarendGarvelink mentions, you should use a reverse proxy for this situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are trying to make a cross-origin request and that's not allowed by browsers (yes, the same hostname with a different port counts as a different origin for this purpose). You have three options here:

**1. Proxy the request.**

Do this one if you can. Write some code that runs on the :8888 server
that proxies requests to the 1337 one. You can also do this by
    sticking a proxy in front of both of them, something like Nginx is
    pretty good at this and easy to set up

**2. Use CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing)**

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control

This means adding some headers to your responses to tell the browser that cross-origin requests are ok here. In your Express server add middleware like this:

```
  function enableCORSMiddleware (req,res,next) {
     // You could use * instead of the url below to allow any origin, 
     // but be careful, you're opening yourself up to all sorts of things!
     res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',  "http://localhost:8888");
     next()
  }
 server.use(enableCORSMiddleware);
```

**3. Use JSONP**

This is a trick where you encode your "AJAX" response as Javascript code. Then you ask the browser to load that code, the browser will happily load scripts cross-origin so this gets round the cross-origin issue. It also lets anyone else get round it as well though, so be sure that's what you want!

On the server side you need wrap your response in a Javascript function call, express can do this for automatically if you enable the "jsonp callback" option like this:

```
server.enable("jsonp callback");
```

Then send your response using the "json()" method of response:

```
server.get("/ajax", function(req, res) {
    res.json({foo: "bar"});
});
```

On the client side you can enanble JSONP in jQuery just by changing "json" to "jsonp" in the dataType option:

```
dataType: "jsonp",
```